# Units of ring spectra and completion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Is  there  a known  relation between  the  space  of units  of  a  ring  spectrum, from  stable  homotopy  theory   in  the  sense  of  Ando-Blumberg-Gepner https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3004v2.pdf and  completions  of   spectra,  in the  sense  of   Bousfield -Kan,  et  al?

In  particular,  does  completion  commute  with  p- completion  at  a  prime  p?  Since   the  first  is a  homotopy  colimit  like  tipe  of  construction, and  the  second  one  is a  homotopy  inverse  limit,  this  seems  to  be  unlikely. Is  there  a  spectral  sequence  relating  them ?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the second paragraph and the first.

Comment: Are you asking if taking units commutes with p-completion? If so, then the answer is no because it is also false for ordinary rings: $(R^\wedge_p)^\times \neq (R^\times)^\wedge_p$ as you can see from the example of $\Bbb Z$. However, the issue is almost entirely a $\pi_0$-issue.